# java.lang.Throwable: addInArray in Adapter

Tags: android-recyclerview

Here is the log,
this log shows as many times as the itemView's number.
but my app is still running normally.

> ViewGroup: addInArray been called, this = android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{42c4eeb0 VFED.... .F....ID 0,0-540,876 #7f0e0160 app:id/product_update_rec_view}call stack =
>                                                            java.lang.Throwable: addInArray
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.addInArray(ViewGroup.java:3786)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3740)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3564)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3509)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:585)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:6249)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:6207)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:6195)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1384)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2900)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
>                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15132)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1160)
>                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15132)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1160)
>                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15132)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1037)
>                                                                at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:747)
>                                                                at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
>                                                                at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1133)
>                                                                at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
>                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15132)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
>                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
>                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15132)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
>                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
>                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
>                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15132)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
>                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
>                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15132)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
>                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
>                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
>                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15132)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
>                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
>                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15132)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2323)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2029)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1192)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6231)
>                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
>                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
>                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doFr

Comment: Please follow the SO's guidelines while asking a question! http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception will happen when you try to use `List<View>` in your list's adapter.

It because the views in arraylist will still have a reference, and therefore not be recycled by garbage collection, and this may cause OOM. But the convertView is built for reusability, so it may not crash so easily.